# VisualForce Error Content cannot be displayed: Invalid conversion from runtime type sObject to sObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I want to understand this error as I have never seen this before.

> Content cannot be displayed: Invalid conversion from runtime type
>   L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c to ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c

Background: I am trying to use a visualforce page & extension to view records associated through a lookup (not the related list records, the "parent") I am trying to invoke the standard controller for my `case__c` object in my extension. So, I can put this visual force page in the detail of the `case__c` object. (record details) currently just bringing the name is so I can see if it works. I will bring in other specific fields later on.

But, I wanted to understand the error that I am getting so I can better troubleshoot this. I have researched this, but I do not see much information that describes the error to be.

code:

**Extension:**

```
    public with sharing class CaseParentExt {

    public ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c prods{ get; set; }
    public ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    public CaseParentExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.prods = (ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c)stdController.getRecord();
        this.stdController = stdController;
    }  
    public void CaseParentExt() {

        String prodsId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        prods = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c WHERE Id =: prodsId];
    }

}
```

**VFP:**

```
<apex:page standardController="L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c" extensions="CaseParentExt">
   <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Related Products">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Product Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputText >{!prods.Name}</apex:outputText>   
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>              
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your standard controller in your visualforce page is not the same type as the record returned by the standard controller in your extension class.

Comment: @MartinLezer ahh, I see your logic in this. So to correctly fix this, can I change the standard controller to ICIX_V1__ICIX_Product__c on the visualforce page, and then re-align my prods SELECT statement, because I am grabbing the Id from the ApexPages.currentPage which is a record from the L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c sObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to answer your comment @Jason.
Your CaseParentExt method is useless. Here's the right code for your extension class:

```
public with sharing class CaseParentExt {

    public L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c Case{ get; set; }

    public CaseParentExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        Id caseId = stdController.getId();
        this.Case = [SELECT ICIX_Product__r.Name FROM L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c WHERE Id = :caseId];
    }  

}
```

And the VF page with the right standard controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c" extensions="CaseParentExt">
   <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Related Products">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Product Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputText >{!Case.ICIX_Product__r.Name}</apex:outputText>   
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>              
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: your code gives me a different error. "Content cannot be displayed: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" . So that tells me that there are no ICIX_Product__c records with the same Id as the record I am viewing. And that is correct, there should not be any ICIX_Product__c records with the same Id as my L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c record. So, I am trying to return the ICIX_Product__c record that is related to the L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c. The ICIX_Product__c is the "parent" of the L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c record. (it's only a lookup, not MD)

Comment: Ok I understand. What's the field name of your lookup?

Comment: The lookup is ICIX_Product__r.L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c from the ICIX_Product__c object the API name is L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c, this is a lookup to the L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c object                                                              referenceTo: L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__c
relationshipName: L1dlF0rm0rg__Case__r
soapType: tns:ID
sortable: true
type: reference

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. This should work.

Comment: I appreciate your help, your answer works. I have marked it as the best answer.

Comment: No problem. I hope you understood my solution. Don't hesitate if you have any questions. Best regards.